# ts-jest error when using ES6 modules

Tags: reactjs, typescript, jestjs

I'm getting an 'unexpected token' error while running my tests with ts-jest.

I've set up a minimal repo with my current setup here:
https://github.com/ramoneguru/ts-jest-setup

The preprocessor.js is fine and working. However the `Loading` component in my repo seems to be the problem. Is my setup OK? Did I miss an obvious configuration somewhere?

Comment: unexpected token... what is the token?

Comment: Yeah, so should ts-jest be parsing this file with babel-jest? I thought that's what the `transform` section would do?

Comment: Very close, pushed an update and now I'm getting this error:

({"Object.<anonymous>":function(module,exports,require,__dirname,__filename,global,jest){.loading-text {
                                                                                             ^
    
    SyntaxError: Unexpected token .

Answer (score 0):

Updated the repo and this now works 1/1 tests passed (sans PropTypes warning). Added this line in my "jest" section:

```
"moduleNameMapper": {
    "^.+\\.(css|less|scss)$": "identity-obj-proxy"
}
```

Grab the latest and run a `yarn test -- --no-cache` and it should work :)